# Parsing VB6 syntax

Tags: parsing, vb6

I need to inject some code into an existing VB6 application.

What I would like to do is add logging code to the top of every method across a few hundred vb6 files, logging the method name and parameters with values.

The writing of the code is easy, but where I am struggling a bit is the matching of the method or property header in VB6 syntax, as there appears to be a great number of variations and optional keywords.

Has anyone got any suggestions about how to achieve this?
I have tried and failed with RegEx and have resorted to tokenising the code and looking for token patterns.

Answer (score 17):

It may be easier to write it as a VB6 addin that allows you to enumerate all modules/procedures and insert code to suit.
Alternatively, use [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) which is free and can add headers to individual procedures or new ones automatically.

Comment: +1 for MZTools. Edited the answer to add a link and mention that it was free

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something more robust then regular expressions for a project like this. I don't know of any OSS VB6 parser implementations off hand but I would recommend using a proper tool for this. This activity is sometimes called [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) or Mixins if you were to generalize the approach of injecting code at compile time.

I will take a moment to plug my own tool [meta#](http://metasharp.codeplex.com) which allows you to build a pattern matching grammar for exactly these types of scenarios but you could also use one of many others such as Lexx/Yacc, Flexx/Bison or ANTLR.

But even if you don't use mine specifically here is the general strategy I would take to solve the problem:

1. Create a code transformation (pre-compile) build step
2. Parse the files into an object model
3. Insert new objects into this model representing the logging calls
4. Generate new code files based on that object model
5. Compile the generated code only.
6. Generated code is a build artifact and is never edited or added to source control.

Run this transform step whenever you build.

Comment: Thanks. Your meta# looks promising, I hadn't actually considered making it a build step.

Answer (score 1):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Visual Basic front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/VisualBasicFrontEnd.html) could be used to do this.

DMS parses source text using a front end to abstract syntax trees, and then enables arbitrary analysis/transformation to be applied to those trees.  Many transformation changes can be accomplished using [source-to-source program transformation](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html), in which code is rewritten using "if  you see *this* syntax, replace it by *that* syntax", using the grammar as a way to define abstract placeholders.  This makes it relatively easy to write transformations on code using familiar syntax. This generalizes OP's method of trying to match sequences of tokens.

The OP's problem could be posed as aspect like rewrites of the form:

```
 default domain VisualBasic~VB6;

 rule function_insert_log_call(a: attributes, t: type,
                               i: IDENTIFIER, p: parameters, s:statements) 
    = function -> function
 = " \a FUNCTION \i ( \p ) AS \t
        \s
     END FUNCTION"
 -> "\a FUNCTION \i ( \p ) AS \t
        my_log(\tostring\(\i\))
        \s
     END FUNCTION";

 rule subroutine_insert_log_call(a: attributes,  
                                 i: IDENTIFIER, p: parameters, s:statements)
    = subroutine -> subroutine
 = " \a SUB \i ( \p )
        \s
     END SUB"
 -> " \a SUB \i ( \p )
        my_log(\tostring\(\i\))
        \s
     END SUB";
```

These rewrites are of the form

```
 rule *rulename* ( *patternvars* ) *nonterminal* -> *nonterminal*
 = " *syntaxpattern* " 
 -> " *syntaxpattern* ";
```

The specific rules provided will recognize the function headers and bodies regardless of content/whitespace/comments because they actually match against the ASTs.
The "..." are metaquotes, and what is outside is DMS rule syntax, and inside
is VB6 syntax.  The \n inside the "..." represents an (AST)
parameter that must match a grammar nonterminal N declared in the rule
header as ...n:N....  tostring is a custom meta-function (called with meta parens ( ) )
that converts a tree node argument into a tree node for a literal string.

OP might need more rules than that to handle other cases; perhaps he wants logging
of GOSUB calls, and/or to capture function parameters in the **log** call.

Other answer suggest getting a parser generator and, well, defining VB6 to enable parsing.  It is important to understand that getting the VB6 syntax right is really hard; the langauge is poorly documented and and has some really wierd rules about whitespace, statements-within-lines and statements across line boundaries.  If you don't get this right, you simply can't parse hundreds of files.  We had to define our own grammar (as we have for DMS for
[many other languages](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds)).

You can read more about code instrumentation/logging using program transformations
[here](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf)

Comment: Read my bio; actually I work for Semantic Designs, which offers DMS as a product.  You might argue I *am* Semantic Designs, having founded it, but the more interesting technical truth is that I'm the architect of DMS and I have a really good team of computer scientists who build and test much of the machinery; I still do my fair share.